# Jackrabbit OraclePersistenceManager and JNDI datasources

Tags: oracle, jndi, weblogic12c, jackrabbit

I'm trying to set up a Jackrabbit persistence manager connecting to a preconfigured OracleDB JNDI datasource, using org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager.

(as a bit of background - this is a magnolia app running on weblogic 12c)

My config looks like so

```
<PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.OraclePersistenceManager">
        <param name="driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <param name="url" value="jdbc/myJNDIResource"/>
        <param name="schema" value="oracle" />
        <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="version_" />
        <param name="externalBLOBs" value="false" />
        <param name="databaseType" value="oracle" />
</PersistenceManager>
```

However, I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: 
Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' 
for connect URL 'jdbc/myJNDIResource'
```

I know that the JNDI name is being resolved correctly (if I change the name, it fails to resolve and throws a different error).

Looking at OraclePersistenceManager, it uses oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver as its driver class, which I believe is the Oracle thin driver. However, I don't know if this will even work with a JNDI datasource.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

I can see threads in mailing lists from about 6 years ago with issues with JNDI with OraclePersistenceManager, but nothing recent.

Thanks

Comment: Just some extra info - this is using Jackrabbit 2.8.0 - which is what is bundled with Magnolia 3.5.6 I believe

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this, use the JNDI `InitialContext` to load the driver, as follows:

```
<param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
```

Comment: Marcos, you need to rephrase so that it's not a question if you think this will solve the problem. Otherwise, it needs to be a comment (which you don't have enough reputation to make, yet).